# How do I activate this JQuery fancybox without clicking it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, templates

http://fancybox.net/api

I just want it to load on its own when the page loads.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check step 6 on [Tips & tricks](http://fancybox.net/blog): "Start FancyBox on page load". Extract:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $.fancybox(
        '<h2>Hi!</h2><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam quis mi eu elit tempor facilisis id et neque</p>',
        {
                'autoDimensions'    : false,
            'width'                 : 350,
            'height'                : 'auto',
            'transitionIn'      : 'none',
            'transitionOut'     : 'none'
        }
    );
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#fancybox-class").trigger('click');
});
```